# Why does the m: n relationship in the DB design have to create a new relation?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I recently learned about DB design. However, in the m: n relation, we need to create a new relation. I do not understand this reason well.
I also wonder why I place a foreign key in n relations instead of 1 when I have a 1: n relationship.

Comment: So imagine I have a student taking courses from a school.

I have a student entity and a course entity.

Would I have to duplicate records in either table in order to support the m:n relationship? (yep)  is duplication bad (yep) so now we add a 3rd table studentCoures.  Now I can take the PK from Student and coures table and support the m:n w/o duplication! (plus I can track other information about the association like the semester/year/ etc...).  When you have 1:N relationship you just need a POInter back to the table  So student gender (M/F/O)  student has the FK to Gender Table PK.

Comment: You place the foreign key in the N relations table because that is the table where the relevant data resides. If you have Customers & Addresses (1:N) you place a "Foreign Key" ON Addresses TO the Customers table. This way, you can prevent records from being created in the Addresses table that do not have an existing Customer record.

Comment: Mock up the data in a M:N w/o a 3rd table in excel or on paper.  Do you start to repeat values to support the M:N relation?  Is that a good thing?

Comment: @xQbert Please let me know more

Comment: M:N must be normalized or you have data redundancy in the database which is a BAD thing (most of the time  sometimes you do it for performance but that's a different story.) You in essence must duplicate the entire student or course record above to show all the courses for a student, or you end up having multiple values in 1 field (WHICH fails 1st normal form)   If you want more help write up sample data w/ an example you're struggling with which we can walk though; and ask questions specific to that mockup/data

Comment: @xQbert Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does "place a foreign key in n relations instead of 1" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally, Chen's method for mapping the entity-relationship model to the relational model prescribed that *every* relationship map to a separate relation (table). However, it's become common practice to denormalize one-to-one and one-to-many relationship relations into entity relations with the same determinant/key, to limit the number of tables in a database. The persistence of network data model thinking (records with references) also helps to popularize this approach. However, not all relationship relations can be denormalized - M:N binary as well as ternary and higher relationships have keys that involve multiple entity sets, and so necessarily require their own relations/tables.

For example, consider the following conceptual models:

[image: ER diagram]

A direct mapping of each entity relation and relationship relation to separate tables would give the following physical models:

[image: Table diagram 1]

Note that the one-to-one relationship `Manages` has two candidate keys, but the physical schema requires that we choose one as primary key. I chose `department_id` since denormalization of the relationship relation into the `Employee` entity relation would require a nullable column (since not every `Employee` is a manager).

More importantly, note that the N:1 and 1:1 relationship tables have the same keys as one of the entity tables. We can take advantage of this to combine those relations:

[image: Denormalized relationships table diagram]

However, the M:N and M:N:P relationships have composite keys, and can't be combined with other tables (unless, in a larger model, you coincidentally have multiple relationships with the same cardinalities between the same entity sets).

> I also wonder why I place a foreign key in n relations instead of 1 when I have a 1: n relationship.

It's more correct to say that a relationship is determined by the combination of its independent entity sets. Values of these sets can appear any number of times, as indicated by M, N, etc. We indicate dependent entity sets with a 1 - these act similar to attributes, in that each unique combination of values in the independent roles determines a single value for each dependent role. This is the logical concept of functional dependency.

When we denormalize tables as above, we do so based on matching keys, which means only dependent columns get transferred from one table to another. In the end, it may look like we added a single FK column to the entity table on the many side of the relationship, but we actually added a mapping from the key to the dependent column, and we just didn't need to repeat the key.