# Entity relationship with one to many foriegn keys

Tags: mysql

This is more of a question on best practice/efficiency optimization, while also helping me to unstick myself.

I need to make a database that simulates a video game company. I have the project entity along with a assigned employee roster for that specific project, and employee entity with foreign keys relating to them from the project roster. I have to add different pay types such as a contractor, an intern, and a full time employee. Along with this I have to divide the employees themselves up into four separate groups to indicate if they are a programmer, an artist, a designer, a tester, or a producer. What might be the most efficient way to handle this while maintaining database query flexibility?

An idea that I had was to attempt to make a bridge entity for both pay types and employee types, but I got stuck thinking I might need to have foreign keys to each respective type table from the pay type bridge, or the employee type bridge, and that would simply be redundant on the query side, along with it yielding the wrong individuals upon a query.

Is there a way I could make a composite key that might look at an attribute of an entity, and assign them as a member of the indicated employee type?
For example:

```
emp_ID       lname    fname  assigned_project     FK_pay_type_ID
123456       Shelly   Mary          21             65(contractor)            

emp_type

designer(this could be read and a script could assign her to the designer table?)
```

To Give an idea of what I am thinking of doing here is a couple of tables I mocked up in Visio:

[Visio Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A16un.jpg) (I really have to have arbitrary site points just to post an image that clarifies my question? Really?)

```
Project               Project_Roster        Employee
FK_projectState ----> PK_projectRoster_ID   <list employee credentials here>
PK_Project_ID         FK_Employee_ID ------>FK_assignedRoster_ID
projectName                                 FK_payType_ID  (goes to bridge)
launchDate                                  FK_EmployeeType_ID(goes to bridge)



Employee_PayType_BR
PK_payType_ID (pointed to specific type depending on assigned?)
FK_Employee_ID
description
amount_Offered
amount_paidToDate("salary" if full time)


#Not sure how to get here

PayType - Contractor
PK_Contractor_ID
FK_Employee_ID
parent_company
skill_set(list | array)


PayType - Intern

PK_Intern_ID
FK_Employee_ID
```

Perhaps there is a simpler way, and I am just missing it, and in that case I apologize for my ineptitude.

Comment: I would like to help you but there is to much tgoing on. Could you detail a little further? 1. Can an employee have multiple skills (programmer, artist, designer) or just one?. 2. Can the same employee be part of more than one project at the same time? 3. Each employeed is either a contractor, an intern or a fulltime worker? (Just to start the conversation)

Comment: You seem to be incorrectly modelling relationsships. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44057979) for an overview. E.g. you cannot have `FK_assignedRoster_ID` in `employee` *AND* `FK_Employee_ID` in `Project_Roster`, instead you'd use a `Project_Roster`-table `(PK_Project_ID, PK_Employee_ID)`. That's the n:m-case, `works_in` corresponds to your `project_roster`. All your relations seem to suffer from this problem, causing your headache. Your concrete requirements are a bit unclear/confusing though, see eduardos comment, so we can't give you a proper model yet.

Comment: Also, as a general design note: you can (and maybe should) model your entire database as an erd first (basically looking like the upper image in the linked answer), drawing entities and especially the links between them, until you like the result/until all your requirements are met. This is actually the hard part. Creating actual tables/fks from this is a trivial step, you basically just have to pick the corresponding table(s) from the lower 2 pictures (or let an erd tool do this, although your should do it by hand a couple of times first).

Comment: For the first comment: No I was only going to set it so an employee could only a programmer, artist, designer, tester, or a producer at one time, and an employee may only be apart of one project at a time, and only be a contractor, full time, or intern at one time, but with flexibility to be brought on as full time.

Comment: For the second comment, The way I had it was I had a project roster table that essentially functioned itself as a bridge table but only in a one to one sense, so a project would have one roster, and in this roster would be a list of employees that would be connect to via a foreign key in the employee table. so: employee would have the details on said employee as well as a FK to the assigned roster, their payType, and their employeeType. Problem is the roster table just has a PK for itself an a FK to employee IDs, making it questionable if it even needs to exist.

Comment: For the third comment, I do have an ER diagram that I made before this question, but I did not know how to upload it onto here. I have not implemented this at all into mySQL yet.

Comment: Looking through that linked answer in the second comment, I am realizing I am treating the whole idea of the employee type wrong and should perhaps make a table that says skill_set and just link to an employee ID and add to that column their skill sets such as programming languages, art styles, preferred game genres for testing, etc and just leave room for null in the even that an employee does not have an art style or programming knowledge.. I am sorry if this question seems rather inane or stupid. I am still very much learning.

Comment: I "uploaded" an image of the ER diagram I made regarding this particular question.